# Problems downloading a binary file with aws-sdk

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, knox-amazon-s3-client

I'm switching my server over from knox to the official aws-sdk, but I'm having some discrepancies with the end results.

In aws-sdk, I use [getObject](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3/Client.html#getObject-property) to get a file in this manner:

```
svc.client.getObject({Bucket:"someBucket", 
    Key:file,
    ResponseContentEncoding:"application/octet-stream"}, 
        function(err, data) {
            if(!err)
            {
                var buff = new Buffer(data.Body, "binary");
                var fd = fs.openSync(file + ".aws", "w");
                fs.writeSync(fd, buff, 0, buff.length,0);
            }
        });
```

I'm getting a file which appears to be a few bytes off, but when I compare it in a hex editor like BeyondCompare, a large number of bytes are off being replaced with 'FD'.  Any insight on this?

Answer (score 2):

Got it:

```
var writePos = 0;
var stream = fs.createWriteStream("/tmp/test.jpg", { flags: 'w', encoding: null, mode: 0666 });
s3.client.getObject({ Bucket: bucket, Key: key }).data(function(data) {
    stream.write(data.data);
}).done(function() {
    stream.end();
}).send();
```

**Edit 9th of Jan 2012:** There was an update to the library, if you're using latest from github:

```
var stream = fs.createWriteStream("/tmp/test.jpg", { flags: 'w', encoding: null, mode: 0666 });
s3.client.getObject({ Bucket: bucket, Key: key }).on('httpData', function(chunk) {
    stream.write(chunk);
}).on('complete', function() {
    stream.end();
}).send();
```

This was introduced in the following pull request: https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js/pull/22